# ¿Por qué este código da error? if nombre == Juan

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy comenzando un curso de programación, y en una de mis funciones me surgió un error que parece bastante sencillo pero que no tengo idea de a qué se debe. La parte del código que me da error es la siguiente:

```
def programa1():

    print("¿Cómo es tu nombre?")
    nombre = input()
    if nombre == Juan:
        print("Hola Juan.")
    else:
        print(f"Un gusto, {nombre}. ¿Cuántos años tenés?")
```

El error que me da es que el nombre "Juan" no está definido. Intenté poner el nombre tanto con como sin comillas, pero me da el mismo error.

Comment: Buenas, lo que te ocurre es que quieres comparar un string por lo que tendrías que indicar "Juan" no solo Juan, ya que se podría confundir como una variable.

Answer (score 14):

Te comento lo siguiente, en esta línea

```
if nombre == Juan:
```

El intérprete no identifica `Juan` como una palabra reservada; es decir que este dentro del léxico reservado de Python

Lo correcto sería

```
if nombre == 'Juan':
```

Por que nombre es una variable que tiene contenido un valor en formato de cadena de texto; entonces si quieres revisar que el nombre ingresado sea igual a Juan; entonces debes ponerlo entre comillas

He revisado y probado tu código y es funcional solo con el cambio que te indico; pruebalo en este plataforma: https://repl.it/repls/DeterminedStrikingSymbol

Al final tu script debería lucir así:

```
def programa1():

    print("¿Cómo es tu nombre?")
    nombre = input()
    if nombre == 'Juan':
        print("Hola Juan.")
    else:
        print(f"Un gusto, {nombre}. ¿Cuántos años tenés?")

programa1()
```

Answer (score 3):

> El error que me da es que el nombre "Juan" no está definido.

Este error se muestra ya que se esta considerando lexicográficamente a `Juan` como una palabra reservada y no como una cadena, para que sea una cadena debe ser contenido entre comillas dobles `"`:

"Juan"

Se debe realizar de esta forma:

```
if nombre == "Juan":
        print("Hola Juan.")
else:
        print(f"Un gusto, {nombre}. ¿Cuántos años tenés?")
```

Si vas a realizar una comparación de cadenas revisa:

[Comparación de cadenas en Python](https://thepythonguru.com/python-strings/)

> Puedes usar (>, <, <=, <=, ==,! =) Para comparar dos cadenas. Python
>   compara la cadena lexicográficamente, es decir, utiliza el valor ASCII
>   de los caracteres.
>
> Supongamos que tiene str1 como "Mary" y str2 como "Mac". Se comparan los dos primeros caracteres de str1 y str2 (M y M). Como son
>   iguales, se comparan los dos segundos personajes. Como también son
>   iguales, se comparan los terceros dos caracteres (r y c). Y como 'r'
>   tiene un valor ASCII mayor que 'c', str1 es mayor que str2.

ejemplos:

```
>>> "tim" == "tie"
False
>>> "banana" == "banana"
True
>>> "free" != "freedom"
True
>>> "arrow" > "aron"
True
>>> "right" >= "left"
True
>>> "teeth" < "tee"
False
>>> "yellow" <= "fellow"
False
>>> "abc" > ""
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print("¿Cómo es tu nombre?")
nombre = input().lower()
a="juan"

if nombre == a:
    print("Hola Juan.")
else:
    print(f"Un gusto, {nombre.capitalize()}. ¿Cuántos años tenés?")
```

---

Uso .lower() por si introduces un nombre en minúsculas, para que pueda compararse con juan.

Defino la variable a="juan" para tener algo con qué comparar.

Luego uso de .capitalize por si introduces un nombre en minúsculas, para que lo escriba correctamente.